# Add value to a row in MySQL if it's greater than another value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table, Users, that contains a unique id, an integer 'econ', and some other irrelevant data. I'm trying to create a SQL statement for a simple gambling implementation. I have access to the user id, the amount bet, and the amount they potentially win. I need to verify that the user currently possesses more money than the total bet and if so UPDATE the row to Users.econ + winnings. (If the user lost the bet I'm simply using a negative number as the winnings value). I can do this with a couple separate statements but I'd prefer to use one so I don't have to deal with transactions.

### Model:

**User:** id (varchar), econ (integer), other

### Current implementation:

- SQL: SELECT econ from Users WHERE id = 'xyz'
- Logic: if (econ > bet) newEcon = econ + winnings, else throw error
- SQL: UPDATE Users SET econ = newEcon WHERE id = 'xyz'

### Desired Result:

**Example 1:**

> User model: id: 10, econ: 300
>
> SQL request: id: 10, bet: 200, winnings: 300
>
> Result: User: id: 10, econ: 600

**Example 2:**

> User model: id: 5, econ: 50
>
> SQL request: id: 5, bet: 100, winnings: 500
>
> Result: User: id: 5, econ: 50 (unchanged)

**Example 3:**

> User model: id: 12, econ: 200
>
> SQL request: id: 12, bet: 100, winnings: -100
>
> Result: User: id: 12, econ: 100

Comment: Can there be more than one bet per user? If so, how do you decide which one to use to compare the value of `bet` with the user's `econ` value?

Comment: The bet will not be stored inside the database and is simply a variable name I'm using when drafting the SQL statement. Each request will be for a single bet. If a user wishes to make multiple bets then multiple requests would be made sequentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to integrate the comparison into your `UPDATE` query:

```
UPDATE users
SET econ = econ + ?
WHERE econ > ? AND id = ?
```

Here I've used placeholders on the assumption you would prepare the query, in order they are for `winnings`, `bet` and `id`

Answer (score 1):

this query is working :

```
update accbalance set econ = econ + @winnings where id=@id and econ > @bet ;
```

Next time please create a sqlfiddle , it can help .

the query was tested in :
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/960009/1 .

Comment: Honestly I had no idea that sqlfiddles existed. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: @NickAbbott they are a great playground, I almost always use one for my answers. I do find sqlfiddle a little unreliable at times so tend to use db-fiddle.com or dbfiddle.uk instead.